# ASP.Net Core MVC error when authorize user more than two roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have 3 projects: ASP.Net Core Web API(localhost:5001), Identity Server 4(localhost:5000) and ASP.Net Core MVC(localhost:5002). The MVC call the API to get data. In the IDS4 I configured like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() => new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("backend_api","Backend API")
        };

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() => new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResource("roles","User role(s)",new List<string>{"role"})
        };
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() => new List<Client>
        {
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId="mvc_admin",
                ClientSecrets={new Secret("secret_key_mvc".ToSha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes=GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireConsent=false,
                RequirePkce=true,
                RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris={ "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "backend_api",
                    "roles"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess=true,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh=true,
            },
}
```

and I have a ProfileService for IDS4 like this to add roles and username to access token and also added them in id token (In API project I use roles from access token to authorize user):

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "role"||x.Type=="name"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

The start up file in MVC project:

```
services.AddAuthentication(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                config.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config=> {
                config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied";
                config.LogoutPath = "/Home/Index";
            })
             .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
             {
                 config.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 config.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerHost"];
                 config.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
                 config.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
                 config.SaveTokens = true;
                 config.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                 config.Scope.Add("backend_api");
                 config.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                 config.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
                 config.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
                 config.Scope.Add("roles");
                 config.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                 config.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                 config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                 {
                     RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
                 };
               
             });
```

And I use `[Authorize(Roles = "WarehouseStaff,Administrator,Cashier,Receptionist")]`in HomeController of MVC project .If the user has one of 4 roles above it's ok, the user has login successfully. But I add one more roles then I redirected to Access Denied Path.
I'm a newbie, anyone can tell me what's the problem with my code =(( Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem when we increase the max size of the HTTP query and cookie on the WEB SERVER (Nginx) the problem was gone.